# Missing line breaks in Git editor (using notepad on Windows)

Tags: git, git-config

I've been trying to set up *notepad* as the default, global editor, for Git.

Invoking *notepad* is now working fine. Here's what my config file looks like:

```
[user]
    name = Gavin Hope   
    email = gavin.hope@myemailaddress.com

[core]
    autocrlf = true
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\Gavin.Hope\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
    editor = 'C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe'

[diff]
    tool = p4merge

[merge]
    tool = p4merge

[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false
```

**However**, when *notepad* launches, e.g. with `git commit`, there are no line breaks. I see this:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.## Date:      Wed Oct 28 11:40:40 2015 +0000## On branch playtime# Changes to be committed:#   modified:   file.xyz#
```

Rather than (something like):

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Wed Oct 28 11:40:40 2015 +0000
#
# On branch playtime
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   file.xyz#
```

**Note 1:** this is only a problem with the line breaks in the configured editor, everything else to do with `autocrlf` is ok.

**Note 2:** in the previous attempt to configure the editor (which didn't fully work) the line breaks in the editor were *normal*.

Am I missing an argument or parameter for the `editor`? Is there something wrong in my config?

Comment: I don't think you can use notepad for this. Notepad does not handle UNIX-style line endings, and I don't think it is possible to configure git to create its commit message files with Windows-style line endings. I suggest you switch to notepad++.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was considering which editor to use and decided *"whilst I haven't decided I'll just use notepad"*. I'll update the title of the question to include notepad, so it's immediately obvious that the editor in question is part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by codeape, *notepad* doesn't work for this job.

I've switched to Notepad++ and that works fine. So that it's clear for anyone else with the same problem, or similar, this is what my `.gitconfig` file looks like now:

```
[user]
    name = Gavin Hope
    email = gavin.hope@myemailaddress.com

[core]
    autocrlf = true
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\Gavin.Hope\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
    editor = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe'

[diff]
    tool = p4merge

[merge]
    tool = p4merge

[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = false
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use notepad.exe, have a look at [GitPad](https://github.com/github/GitPad).

GitPad is a wrapper executable around notepad.exe that takes the git-created commit-file and converts to/from Windows-style line endings.